# Set local variable in method inside the html in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have this method render, within which I am creating a local variable `category`. I need to set the value of this variable inside the html in return statement using JSX.

I am using curly brackets to assign the value to the local variable, but this is not working for me. eg `{category='business'}`

This is what I am doing currently

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let category = 'about';
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavBar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/about">
            </Route>
            <Route path="/business">
              {category='business'}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/entertainment">
              {category='entertainment'}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/general">
              {category='general'}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/health">
              {category='health'}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/science">
              {category='science'}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/sports">
              {category='sports'}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <News pageSize={5} country="in" category={category}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

This one instead shows the category on screen.

**Note :** I know there are multiple ways in which I can achieve this but I wanted to know how to set local variable within my method

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, look into functional components.
2. A Route component expects a component, not logic. Handle the actual variable change in that component or elsewhere via react-router's [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

What you're attempting to do is to change the state of the variable. Cue React's [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hooks (the component needs to be a functional component for hooks to work).

First import the hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
```

Then, in your case:

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState('about') // initial value
```

and when you need to update it:

```
setCategory('science') // new value
```

Comment: If I use, use state to do the same it gets stuck in render-rerender loop

Comment: Are you attempting to set it in <Route>?

Comment: Yes, setting or updating it inside route

Comment: Like I said in my answer, no logic belongs in <Route>. Your route should look like             <Route path="/About" component={AboutComponent} />, no logic inside.